# Run the script in context of parent window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, browser

I would like to run javascript in the context of the parent (to the iframe) window. I have a full control on the iframe content, but cannot directly load scripts in parent window.

**Use Case**: Parent page contains menu items, and based on the menu selection it loads an iframe content. I need to load a script in the iframe and execute it in context of the parent window so it keeps alive/persistent even if I navigate our of the iframe. Same domain.

[image]

DOM Script injection works, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: Upvoted for the illustration.

Comment: So inject the script into the parent

Comment: Script injection works fine, but an audit doesn't like it. That's why I'm looking for other options (if there are any)... even complex, but without script injection.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this solution faces any limitations in your case. Try to load JS script in your iframed content:

`<script src="iframed.js"></script>`

and inside of `iframed.js`:

```
// call function with context of parent window, and pass window and document as parameters. 
foo.call(window.parent, window.parent, window.parent.document);

function foo(window, document) {
    // now you can access all globals from the main window:
    var target = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    // logs collection of iframes from the main window:
    console.log('iframes from main window:', target);
    // global context is main window
    console.log('global context: ', this);
}
```